# Каким образом изменить внешний вид выпадающего списка редактора коллекции propertygrid

Tags: c#, winforms, vb.net, propertygrid

Имеется стандартный редактор коллекции с перегруженным базовым классом.
Хотелось бы изменить внешний вид выпадающего списка, например некоторые строки выделить жирным шрифтом или другим цветом. Можно ли это сделать и как если можно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WinForms не дает много поля для кастомизации (или дает, но с боем). Кое-что сделать можно.

Для любого типа/свойства можно переопределять редактор с помощью атрибута `Editor`:

```
public class Foo
{
    [Editor(typeof(CustomEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

Для этого нужно имплементировать `UITypeEditor`:

```
public class CustomEditor : UITypeEditor
{
    public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        // говорим, что это будет выпадающий список
        // есть вариант Modal, при котором мы можем показать форму в качестве редактора
        return UITypeEditorEditStyle.DropDown;
    }

    public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.IServiceProvider provider, object value)
    {
        // context -- содержит информацию о текущем свойстве и родительском объекте

        // provider -- дает сервис, с помощью которого можно отображать кастомные редакторы

        // value -- содержит непосредственно редактируемый объект

        IWindowsFormsEditorService service = (IWindowsFormsEditorService)provider.GetService(typeof(IWindowsFormsEditorService));

        var list = new ListBox()
        {
            SelectionMode = SelectionMode.One,
            DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed
        };
        // не забываем закрыть выпадающий список после того, как было выбрано значение
        list.SelectedValueChanged += (s, e) => service.CloseDropDown();
        list.DrawItem += (s, e) =>
        {
            // кастомизация шрифта (жирный/нежирный)
            e.DrawBackground();
            var font = e.Index % 2 == 0
                ? new Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Bold)
                : new Font("Arial", 9);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(
                list.Items[e.Index].ToString(),
                font,
                Brushes.Black,
                e.Bounds);
            e.DrawFocusRectangle();
        };

        // заполняем список ерундой
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++ )
        {
            list.Items.Add(i.ToString());
        }

        // устанавливаем текущее значение в качестве выбранного
        list.SelectedItem = value;

        // показываем выпадающий список, показывать можно любой контрол
        service.DropDownControl(list);

        // возвращаем выбранное в списке значение в качестве нового значения
        return list.SelectedItem;
    }
}
```

Само приложение:

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Form form = new Form()
        {
            Controls =
            {
                new PropertyGrid()
                {
                    Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
                    SelectedObject = new Foo()
                }
            }
        };
        Application.Run(form);
    }
}
```

---

Еще несколько кратких примеров можно найти в [статье на CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9517/PropertyGrid-and-Drop-Down-properties).

Comment: Спасибо. как только мне удасться переписать это на VB и получить положительные результаты, отмечу ваш ответ как верный.